# Question the structure weight capacity

Tags: garage, structural, support

previous owner built an attic above the garage w/ a ladder plus shelves on all walls. heaviest items in attic is a container (L24xW16xH12) <20lbs. side wall is holding drums evenly dispersed. Should I worry? I’ll try to get the best pic to show. There the attic view above and a corner view to see the shelves, attic and hopefully enough to get an idea of the [[image: ![enter image description here][1]][1] structure]

Comment: worry about what? ... what's in the drums? ... why didn't the previous owner take them when moving out?

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you concerned about the attic or the side shelves?

Comment: The loft looks engineered. Those look like rafter ties coming in from the left to butt into the truss with the storage. From that truss, though, it looks like the rafter tie load path is through the floor sheathing up there. I can't quite tell from the photo. Can you take another photo looking up at the floor's underside that also includes a bit of the rafter ties? Probably uninhabitable attic with storage under Chapter 3 of the IRC. I think that would make it a 20 psf live load area, but I'd appreciate if somebody could confirm.

Comment: For shelving, if the loft is engineered for storage, then I anticipate that the shelves are fine. Especially if it's basically the same storage as the loft but hanging down a few feet for more headroom. Even with all sorts of images, we'd still need to make assumptions about the truss strength, so "I don't know" is probably the best responsible answer that you're going to get.